# How to enable the Rest API request and Response logging in Consumer side of Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, rest, web-services

Is there any eclipse plugin like TCP/IP monitor to log/view each and every internal rest API call requests and response ? or How to log the internal rest API call request and response in consumer side without touching the consumer code in Spring Boot Application?